# How do I get attribute values of event sources inside listeners

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to add an onclick event listener to jquery datatable paginate buttons.

Below I am trying to check if the pagination button which is clicked is active or not

```
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
           drawCallback: function(){
           var pb = $('.paginate_button');
           alert(JSON.stringify(pb));

           $(pb,this.api().table().container()).on('click',function(){
             //Logic to get which pagination button was clicked and get to know if the button was disabled . 
                    //Something like : this.class
           });       
         }
  });
```

How can I get to know the event source in such cases.

Comment: You just wanted to add onclick event listener pagination button right? if i'm not wrong.

Comment: Thats right....

Comment: check below solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below to get click button properties

```
       $(document).ready(function (){

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
               drawCallback: function(){
               var pb = $('.paginate_button');



                         $(pb,this.api().table().container()).on('click',function(){
                 //Logic to get which pagination button was clicked and get to know if the button was disabled . 
                        //Something like : this.class
 alert("You have click button    :" + this.text);                                
  if ($( this ).hasClass( "disabled" )) {

  alert("Button you have clicked is disable");

 } else {

   alert("Button you have clicked is enable");
  }




               });       
             }
      });  
 });
```

Also find link jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ajbghfhh/73/

Comment: The second alert(to check active buttons) is firing for all buttons.

Comment: Idea is to apply some logic only if the active button was clicked. But in above logic how do I know if the button clicked was an active button or not

Comment: @starhunter please check updated answer also js fiddle link

Comment: button clicked was an active button or not ? what does it mean i'm not able understand it.

Comment: Example: When table loads 'Previous' button is greyed out(disabled), if user clicks on Previous button he should know he clicked a disabled(inactive) button, hence don't perform any action. Similarly when user is at the last page ,when he clicks on 'Next' button, he should know that he is clicking on a disabled button .

Comment: @starhunter please check the solution now also js fiddle link